# Choosing of AWS Load Balancer for Kubernetes HA cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am trying to implement CI/CD pipeline for my set of microservices by using Kubernetes HA cluster and Jenkins.

When I am exploring, I found that usage of load balancer for making a HA kubernetes cluster. I am planning to host my application in AWS. So I want to create and use an AWS elastic load balancer for my application by supporting HA kubernetes cluster.

My doubt here that, When I am exploring AWS load balancer, I am seeing that "Application Loadbalancer - http/https" and "Network Loadbalancer-TCP".

So here I am confused about which load balancer AWS resources I need to create? 
 In my exploration, I understood that to create a network load balancer.

So my confusion is this. Can anyone clear that I am going in correct direction?
 Means creating network load balancer.

Can anyone correct me if I am going in wrong direction?

Let me know that should network load balancer will solve HA kubernetes cluster formation or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a right answer to your question, it really depends what you need to do. **You can achieve HA with a network load balancer, a classic load balancer (even though this is the old generation and is not suggested) or an application load balancer.**

The advantages of network load balancers are certainly related to performance and the possibility to attach elastic IPs and are ideal for balancing TPC traffic (level 4 routing).

On the other side, application load balancers are ideal for advanced load balancing of HTTP and HTTPS traffic (level 7 routing), with the possibility to do advanced request routing, suitable for complex application architectures (such as microservices)

This link might be useful https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/details/#details

Comment: Hi @Gabriel , it seems you are quite expert about ELB, could you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69364113/jenkins-agents-and-https-on-ec2-behind-elastic-load-balancer-classic-balancer Thank you